# i want to download files when i click on image name or file name in php

Tags: javascript, php, download

```
$path = "https://surv-translation.com/assets/uploads/files/";
$filename = "1544615073screenshot-trustwortha.com-2018.11.29-16-37-46.png";
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');  // For Gecko browsers mainly
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)) . ' GMT');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');  // For download resume
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));  // File size
header('Content-Encoding: none');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');  // Change this mime type if the file is not PDF
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);  // Make the browser display the Save As dialog
readfile($path);
exit;
```

I try with this code but I didn't get any success and I want to download any file like docx, pdf, ppt or image, etc.. so can you help me, please ?

Comment: _"but I didn't get any success"_ - so what happens? You might also want to use `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` instead of hard coding `pdf` (specially since the code is trying to download a png, and not a pdf).

Comment: You can start here `header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); ` but looks like you trying to work with png

Comment: `readfile($path);`, `filemtime($path)` and `filesize($path)` aren't correct either. `$path` only contains the path, not the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code for download any file like **doc**, **pdf**, **ppt** or **image**, etc

```
if (file_exists($filepath)) {
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filepath) . '"');
 header('Expires: 0');
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
 header('Pragma: public');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
 flush(); // Flush system output buffer
 readfile($filepath);
 exit;
 }
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of why the OP should try this. What does it solve and how does it solve it?

Comment: Look, man, I try my best and just give him an example if you have a better answer please share or edit my code

Comment: I'm just trying to help you write a better answer. An answer should always contain an explanation about the what it solves and how. That way, the OP (and future visitors) will learn how to tackle similar issues in the future

Comment: Dear @MagnusEriksson The question doesn't ask any explanation he just wants an example I try to do that simply.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - And tbh, the question should actually be closed since the OP haven't even told us what happens.

Comment: Hello, I call this PHP code using ajax and in response print binary format not open the download blob.

Comment: So why you write PHP? you really need to update your question that what you actually need

Comment: Also, one more thing if you really need to download using ajax then you no need to call PHP